# ERROR:saml2.client_base:XML parse error: Not for me!!! in flask_saml implementation with haproxy

Tags: flask, python-3.7, saml, haproxy

I'm moving a single-server flask implementation to one behind a load balancer. This is working on the single-host but not when I shift things behind the LB. My *assumption* is that its somehow related to signing the response from our idp but I can't seem to find a setting/confg for that in flask_saml.

Python3.7, flask 1.1.2, Flask-SAML 0.4.3, LB is Haproxy

**Flask:**

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__, template_folder=serverconfig['flask']['template_folder'], static_url_path=serverconfig['flask']['static_url_path'])
app.config['SAML_DEFAULT_REDIRECT'] = '/REDACTED/REDACDTED'
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/'
app.config.update({
    'SECRET_KEY': 'REDACTED',
    'SAML_METADATA_URL': 'http://localhost:8001/metadata.xml',
})
if serverconfig['environment'] == 'server':
    saml = flask_saml.FlaskSAML(app)
```

**Error:**

```
[Tue May 05 06:46:58.812556 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1211] [remote LOAD_BALANCER_IP:45692] ERROR:saml2.client_base:XML parse error: Not for me!!!
[Tue May 05 06:47:13.756002 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1211] [remote LOAD_BALANCER_IP:45710] ERROR:saml2.client_base:XML parse error: Not for me!!!
[Tue May 05 06:49:57.454760 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 1211] [remote LOAD_BALANCER_IP:45880] ERROR:saml2.client_base:XML parse error: Not for me!!!
```

Anyinsight or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The "Not for me! ! !" error message means that the response assertion was destined for another entityid. So check your configuration/documentation, debug SAML request.

I guess somewhere will be used entity ID as loadbalancer URL used (e.g. `https://example.com/...`) and flask expecting local URL (e.g. `https://localhost/...`) in the entity ID, because it is not prepared/configured for loadbalancing.